# A certain kind of non-linear mapping from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, examples-counterexamples

Give an example of a map $T:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$ with both of the following properties:

a. $T(kx)=kT(x)$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}^2, k\in \mathbb{R}$

b. $T$ fails to be a linear transformation

I am really stuck on this. I can only find matrices that are not linear transformations and don't fulfill the first condition, or they are linear transformations and they do fulfill the first condition. I am not sure how to go about doing this.

Comment: Looking for matrices for this is the wrong method, as matrices directly correspond to linear transformations (provided you've chosen a basis).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

$$T(x_1,x_2) = \big((x_1^2x_2)^{1/3},x_1+x_2\big)$$

Answer (score 9):

Based on Doug M's strategy, here's a symmetrical one:

$$T(x,y) = \left((x^3+y^3)^\frac{1}{3},(x^3+y^3)^\frac{1}{3}\right)$$

Or, with the same idea, an even simpler one:

$$T(x,y) = \left((x^3+y^3)^\frac{1}{3}\,,\,0\right)$$

Still with the same idea, but dispensing with symmetry, here's a bijective one:

$$T(x,y) = \left((x^3+y^3)^\frac{1}{3},(x^3-y^3)^\frac{1}{3}\right)$$

Comment: +1 for the bijective one. More generally to produce a bijection one may consider any invertible matrix $M$, any odd positive integer $k$, and define $T(x)= (Mx^k)^{1/k}$ to obtain a bijection (where the powers are taken component wise).

Answer (score 8):

What about

$f(x,y) = \begin{cases}  (0,0) & x \ne 0 \\ (x,y) & x = 0\end{cases}\\$

Conceptually, the given condition requires that if we restrict $f$ to any line through the origin, it is linear.  Since each of those lines only overlaps at the origin, we can construct $f$ easily by constructing its value on each of those lines one by one.

In this case, we choose $f$ to be zero on every line except on the y axis.  On the y axis, it just looks like a the identity function.  The function constructed this way is not linear because its value on the y axis doesn't "agree" with its value everywhere else.  If we try to check whether the law of linearity applies, we check two points $p_1, p_2$, and verify that

$f(p_1 + p_2) = f(p_1) + f(p_2)$

Now, if both $p_1$ and $p_2$ are on the y axis, or both of them are *not* on the y axis, this equality will hold.  However, if one of them is on the y axis and the other isn't, you'll run into problems.  For example:

$p_1 = (1,0)$
$p_2 = (1,1)$
$f(p_1+p_2) = f(2,1) = (0,0)$
$f(p_1) + f(p_2) = (1,0) + (0,0) = (1,0)$

In general, you can see that there are infinitely many ways that we could choose different linear functions on all the lines through the origin and "piece together" a novel f that violates the constraints, even a continuous or differentiable one, as other people have demonstrated.

Answer (score 6):

$f(x,y) = \begin{cases}  \frac {x^2}{y} & y\ne 0 \\ 0 & y = 0\end{cases}\\
f(kx,ky) = kf(x,y)$

Here we have a non-linear map from $\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$

now find a $g(x,y)$ along similar lines (or even a linear $g(x)$ at this point.)

and $h(x,y) = f(x,y),g(x,y)$ will do what you need it to do.

Comment: So quick with the -1's. No good reason for that. Make the comment, then give the poster a chance to fix it, or delete it.

Comment: @quasi - At least had the courtesy to comment.  The -1 with no explanation irritate me far more.

Comment: Now the map fails to be homogeneous for $k<0$.

Comment: @DougM I think it's fine to prefer something intuitive but it really must be acknowledged somewhere in the answer instead of presenting it as a complete strategy.

Comment: @DougM: Using your strategy, would $f(x,y) = (x^3+y^3)^{1/3}$ work?

Comment: @DougM I did downvote without initially commenting, but I thought the explanation was apparent (you did indeed know it was incomplete when posting it), and I tend to hold people with obvious experience on the site to high standards.

Comment: @quasi It appears so.

Comment: @ErickWong Have I missed anything now?

Comment: @Doug M: feel free to edit in my suggestion -- it validates your intuitive approach.

Comment: @quasi On the same veine, you may consider 
$$T(x)= \|x\|^{1-\alpha}\big(|x_1|^{\alpha}\operatorname{sign}(x_1),\ldots,|x_n|^{\alpha}\operatorname{sign}(x_n)\big)$$
for any norm $\|\cdot\|$ on $\Bbb R^n$ and any $\alpha>0$.

Comment: @Surb: Do the signs work if $n$ is even?

Comment: @quasi good point :), but well, although I use it very often, I try to avoid the sign function as it is always needed to precise its definition at $0$, ($\operatorname{sign}(0)=0$ in this case). $n$ stands for $T\colon \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^n$ and yes, it works for every $n$. Note that you need $\alpha \in [0,1)$ to avoid linearity and problem at $0$.

Comment: @DougM Looks fine to me.  I'd suggest adding "Then" before the second line to make it clear that the first formula is a definition while the second is a consequence (which should be verified by OP).

Comment: @Surb: Yes, of course -- I misread it as a product instead of an $n$-tuple. Then as in my deleted comment, $\alpha=0$ works nicely.

Answer (score 3):

Generally, any function of the form
$$
f(x) = \left(x_1 g\left(\frac{x_2}{x_1}\right),x_1 h\left(\frac{x_2}{x_1}\right)\right)
$$
This works because $kx_2/kx_1=x_2/x_1$

Note that the value at $x=(0,a)$ should be taken as the limit as $x_1\to 0$ where possible.

Comment: The value at $x=(0,0)$ must always be taken as $(0,0)$ regardless of the limit.  There is no requirement that $f$ be continuous.

Comment: @ErickWong - True, but I was referring to the expression as provided. Then again, it occurs to me that the value when $x_1=0$ is the concern for "dealing with special cases", so I'll adjust the wording.

Comment: Ah that makes more sense, however it's still true that there is no requirement that $f$ be continuous.  Since this is meant to be a general solution, the phrasing "should be taken" seems odd.  Generally, one can choose $f(0,a)$ to be $a$ times an arbitrary constant vector, independent of $g$ and $h$.

Comment: @ErickWong - yes, but then it wouldn't match the form I gave, whereas it is common practice to convert$x_1\frac{x_2}{x_1}$, for example,  into $x_2$ and interpret it as satisfying the given form.

Comment: It makes sense at the level of the OP.  I don't think of it as not matching your form, it's just that the domain of $g$ "wants" to be the real projective line rather than $\mathbb R$.  And the nice case is where $g$ is continuous, but in general $g(\infty)$ isn't obliged to agree with its neighborhood any more than $g(2)$ is :).

Comment: @ErickWong - sure, but that still doesn't address what happens at (0,0), where the expression contains $\frac00$.

Comment: What happens at $(0,0)$ is uniquely determined already.

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by Surd, I slightly generalize his result as follows:

$$T(x_1,x_2) = (\sum_{i=1}^N a_ix_1^{n_{1,i}/n_i}x_2^{n_{2,i}/n_i}, \sum_{j=1}^M b_jx_1^{m_{1,j}/m_j}x_2^{m_{2,j}/m_j}),$$
where $a_i, b_j \in {\mathbb R}$ [$(\prod_{i = 1}^{N} a_i) (\prod_{j = 1}^{M} b_j) \neq 0$], $M,N \in \overline{\mathbb Z}_+$ ($MN \neq 0$), $n_{1,i},n_{2,i},m_{1,j},m_{2,j} \in {\mathbb Z}^+$, $n_{1,i} + n_{2,i} = n_i$, $m_{1,j}+m_{2,j} = m_j$, and $n_i,m_j$ are odd.

Comment: @Surb Thanks very much, and I will modify it.